# What is a person who carries information between two people called?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice, word-request

What  is  a person  called when he carries  information between the two people  who  are  not on talking terms.

He  is not  a broker  or  a gossipper.

Comment: Informally, a [***go-between.***](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/go-between) Or choose from many other synonyms in that link.

Comment: @TypeIA: Please do. I'm not bothered about being "attributed", but be sure to mention that it's relatively ***informal***, in case my above comment gets deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a person could be called a **[messenger](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/messenger)**, an **[intermediary](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/intermediary)** or (casually/informally) a **[go-between](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/go-between)** (courtesy of @FumbleFingers).

> **messenger**: a person who carries a message or goes on an errand for another, especially as a matter of duty or business.
>
> **intermediary**: an intermediate agent or agency; a go-between or mediator.
>
> **go-between**: a person acting as an agent.

Here's an example sentence:

> Alice and Bob were not on speaking terms, so Chuck acted as a go-between.

Comment: @ TypeIA. I have accepted your answer and upvoted it too.

Comment: @ I  believe  gobetween is  the  most  appropriate  word as  Mr Fumble Fingers  pointed  out

Comment: @Englishmonger  it depends on the context.  For what you describe, "intermediary"   is the more formal term, as it literally [means the same thing](https://www.etymonline.com/word/intermediary) as "go-between".  In the context of adjudicating some conflict, you can use "mediator", or, in business, "middleman".